# Foundation: Way to offset inner columns as much as outer columns?

Tags: css, zurb-foundation

I have a few rows set up as such:

```
<div class="header row">
  <div class="small-4 small-offset-1 columns">
  left
  </div>
  <div class="small-7 columns">
  right
  </div>
</div>

<div class="content row">
  <div class="small-5 columns">
    left
    <ul>
    <li class="row">
      <div class="small-9 columns">list info</div>
      <div class="small-3 columns">list info</div>
    </li>
    <li class="row">
      <div class="small-9 columns">list info</div>
      <div class="small-3 columns">list info</div>
    </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="small-7 columns">
    right
  </div>
</div>
```

I want the `li` rows to stretch the full width of their parent `.small-5` column.

But, I want the content of the `li`s - the `.small-9` and `.small-3` to be offset by 1/12 the width of the entire screen, exactly like header row above (`small-4 small-offset-1`).

This fiddle might help explain what I'm trying to do: https://jsfiddle.net/4tp87v60/15/

Would anyone know if this is achievable with Foundation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `small-4` class simply has a margin-left originating from `.small-offset-1` of `8.33333%` (100% / 12).

If I understand you correctly, you simply want to offset the `<ul>` in `small-5`. Unfortunately, the closest you can do by adding Foundation classes is `small-offset-3`, which gives `margin-left: 25%`.

However, there's nothing stopping you adding the correct offset of `27.33333%` manually:

```
.small-5 ul {
  margin-left: 27.33333%;
}
```

I've created a new fiddle showcasing this [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Obsidian_Age/yu5cymq7/).

**EDIT**

In order to simply offset the content of the `<li>` element, you simply need to slightly adjust this to:

```
.small-5 ul .small-9 {
  padding-left: 25%; // Equivalent to three columns at 8.33333%
}
```

A secondary fiddle of this is available [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Obsidian_Age/tsw22agf/).

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to offset the `ul` or the `li`s within. Just the content of the `li`s.

Comment: Ahh, I see, and that **does** make much more sense ;) I'll update my answer to cover this :)

Comment: Yep! I took you're original answer and came to the same conclusion, except, weirdly our maths is different! I got `(12 / 5) * 8.33 = 19.992`

Comment: That's because you're not supposed to divide 12 by 5 ;) You have 100% of the row, and 12 columns. That's where the 8.33 comes from; `100 / 12 = 8.33`. The 5 doesn't come into it at all; you're confusing the parent row, and should instead use 3 (from 12 columns minus the 9 from the `.small-9`). Essentially, 25% comes from `(100 / 12) * (12 - 9)` :)